# Action Bar android change height

Tags: android

I am looking for to change the height of action bar in android in theme.xml, android version 11. ***backgroundColor*** this attribute works but ***android:height*** this doesnot.

@style/CustomActionBar

```
<style name="CustomActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!--  <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_style</item> -->
    <item name="android:height">100dp</item>
    <item name="actionBarSize">100dp</item>
    <item name="backgroundColor">@color/purple_200</item>
</style>
```

Comment: what is your problem? What is not working?

Comment: actionbar height size not changing

Comment: I hvae specified using item name="android:actionBarSize">100dp</item>
    <item name="height">100dp</item>

Comment: height and actionBarSize not working

Comment: <item name="backgroundColor">@color/purple_200</item> its working fine

Comment: <item name="android:actionBarSize">100dp</item>
    <item name="height">100dp</item> and its not working.

Comment: height attribute not working